# Where does data returned by ember-data 'live'?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

ya'll I have a bit of a structural/procedural question for ya.

So I have a pretty simple ember app, trying to use ember-data and I'm just not sure if I'm 'doing it right'. So the user hits my index template, I grab their location coordinates and encode a hash of it (that part works). Then on my server I have a db that stores 'tiles' named after there hash'd coords (if i hit my `#/tiles/H1A2S3H4E5D` route I get back properly formatted JSON).

What I would like to happen next, if to display each of the returned tiles to the user on the bottom of the first page (like in a partial maybe? if handlebars does that).

I have a `DS.Model` for the tiles, if I hard code the Hash'd cords into a `App.find(H1A2S3H4E5D)`; I can see my server properly responding to the query. However, I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to access the returned JSON object, or how to display it to the user.

I did watch a few tutorial videos but they all seem to be outdated with the old router.

Mainly I would like to know:
 1. Where does the information returned by `App.find()`; live & how to access it?
 2. what is the 'correct' way to structure my templates/views to handle this?
 3. how should I pass that id (the hash'd coords) to `App.find`? as a global variable? or is there a better way?

the biggest problem(to me) seems to be that the id I search by doesn't exist until the user hit the page tho first time. (since its dynamically generated) so I can't just grab it when the page loads.

*I can post a fiddle if required, but I'm looking for more of a conceptual/instructional answer rather then some one to just write my code for me*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still learning a lot with Ember as well, but this is my understanding. When you follow the guides and the tutorials out there, you'll have something like this:

```
App.TileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

App.TileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', App.Tile.find(MYHASH));
  }
});
```

What it does is set the special content object to the result. So since we're declaring an object controller, and calling find with a parameter, it knows that a single result is expected. So a view & template that follow the naming convention of `Tile` will be loaded. And in there you can access properties on the Tile object:

```
<p>{{lat}}</p><p>{{lng}}</p>
```

I have to admit that this feels a bit mystical at times. The core to it is all in the naming convention. You need to be pretty specific in how you name all your various controllers, routes, etc. Once that's nailed down, it's a matter of binding what data you want to the controller's content.

1) Aside from the generic answer of "in memory", the .find() calls live where ever you return it to. Generally speaking, this is meant to be set on a 'content' property of a controller.

2) I more or less answered this, but generally speaking you take the name of your route, and base it off that. So for a route `TileRoute`, you have:

- TileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
- Tile = DS.Model.extend
- TileView = Ember.View.extend
- tile.handlebars

I generally store all my handlebars files in a templates/ folder. If you nest them deeper, just specify the path in your view object:

```
App.TileView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "tiles/show"
});
```

3) This really depends on your app. Generally speaking its better for the id to be either obtained from the URL, or constructed locally in a function. Since you are encoding a hash, i imagine you're doing this in a function, and then calling find. I do something a bit similar for an Array controller.

I don't know at what point you are generating a hash, so let's say it's onload. You should be able to generate the hash just in the setupController function.

```
App.TileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  generateHashBasedOnCoords: function() {
    // ...
  },
  setupController: function(controller) {
    var MYHASH = this.generateHashBasedOnCoords();
    controller.set('content', App.Tile.find(MYHASH));
  }
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Mystical is about right! I think I get what your saying... Well at lest enough to make it work... kinda, but I am still a little confused about something. When I hit `#/tiles` the console tells me `Transitioned into 'tiles.index'`, or `#tiles/MYHASH` it tell me `Transitioned into 'tiles.tile'`... but they render the same template, the former lists all my tiles, the latter the same, but with the queried tile amended to the list. What is that transition... a View? a Route? *(I do have a single tile template, I just can't seem to hit it)*

Comment: transitionTo is for a route. Not to be more confusing, but if you keep the setup super simple, you don't even need a view a lot of the time. Views are mainly for setting the template, and in some cases events. Since you're using tested, make sure you have the proper setup to support it. `TilesTileController` `TilesTileRoute` `tiles/tile.handlebars`

Comment: Thats not confusing its actually exactly what I was thinking. Its seem that its an issue of what to call things. How do you deduce the names of these things? I cant seem to find more then a light weight example *(or maybe that all there is and I am over thinking it!)*

Comment: I think having practice with rails development has helped, but the names of everything is derived from the route. From there, it's simply Capitalized casing for each word. If you have nested, the nested word also starts with a capital. Let's say you have two routes: `this.resource("news_paper")` `this.resource("news_paper.show")`. You would get the `NewsPaperRoute` `NewsPaperController`, as well as `NewsPaperShowRoute` `NewsPaperShowController`. Makes sense? It's pretty automatic on how they're generated. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ look at the 2nd table.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I guess it is as simple as it seems, I guess it just feels like there should be more too it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can make use of the data binding in ember and basically have an array controller for tiles and set the content initially to an empty array.  Then we you get back your response do a App.find() and set the content of the tiles controller with the data that is returned.  This should update the view through the data binding. (Very high level response)

The data itself is stored in a store that is setup with ember data.  You access it with the same method you are using the model methods App.Tile.find() ect.  It checks to see if the data  that is needed is in the store if so it returns the data otherwise it makes a call to the api to get the data.